# LocationManager, GPS and Network providers.. are triggered both?

Tags: android, network-programming, gps, android-location

This code:

```
ServiceListener mlistener = new SosServiceListener(getApplicationContext());

manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

manager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mlistener, null);
manager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mlistener, null);
```

Attach a listener once to two events. The fact is: if both events are triggered, the listener is called twice? If yes, how would you prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: for that purpose only if-else loop was created...

Comment: create two diff listener one for network provider and other for GPS provider and read both results. Based on your interest you may cancel/stop listining either GPS or network provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used for one of my projects and is perfectly working:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,  MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,  MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            lat = location.getLatitude();
                            lng = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //get the location by gps
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (mLocationManager != null) {location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                lat = location.getLatitude();
                                lng = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Comment: are these constants defined somewhere or I can set my values as I see fit? if that's the case what values should i assign them?

Comment: There are no constants here, lat and lng are double variables, isGPSEnabled and isNetworkEnabled are boolean variables initially set to false, mLocationManager is an instance of LocationManager.

Comment: @TharakaNirmana I think he meant, these constants MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES. @ libathos And if is so, yes you can change. MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES is in miliseconds, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES is in meters. [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that devices will be running on device with Google Play installed - much better way is to use this service: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html